# AMI Instance redirecting

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, redirect

I have recently imaged an AWS EC2 Instance that a colleague (who is no longer working with me) originally set up.

I have launched another instance from this image, and I am able to SSH in etc with no issues. I want to visit the new image from it's IP however when I visit the IP I am redirected to the website, that the original imaged server is hosting.

At first I thought fair enough this must be something in the Nginx config that is causing it, however I have since stopped the `nginx` service, and the `php5-fpm` service and it still appears to redirect me so I can only assume that this setting is not local to the server

Could there be anywhere else I can look such as perhaps an AWS setting? any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's highly unlikely this is an AWS setting. What's the server running? WordPress?

Comment: Nginx stack with PHP and MySQL (Original server was behind a loadbalancer if that helps), curiously enough if I hit the public IP it redirects to the old server (or loadbalancer I assume) but the public DNS (ec2.xx.xx.eu.compute.amazonaws.com) fails to connect alltogether

Comment: I know it's running Nginx/PHP, that's in your question. What PHP - WordPress, some sort of custom app?

Comment: Just a custom website, no framework.

Comment: Are you certain you have the right IP? Without nginx/php running, nothing should be responding at all (unless your browser has cached a 301 response).

Comment: Same IP that I am SSHing in with and stopping the nginx and php services. When I run service --status-all they both have an "-" next to them, so I'm fairly certain. HOWEVER I have just tried from a private browser and it looks like theres no connection at all, so this might be it!

Comment: Have just restarted them and gone from private browser and getting redirected, so yes it looks like a cache and don't I just feel like a prize plum. Thank you for your time, hopefully I can figure it out from here